# How can I extract certain attributes from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a JSON file:

```
{
    "business_id": "5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw",
    "full_address": "4734 Lebanon Church Rd\nDravosburg, PA 15034",
    "hours": {
        "Friday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Monday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        }
    },
    "open": true,
    "categories": ["Fast Food",
    "Restaurants"],
    "city": "Dravosburg",
    "review_count": 4,
    "name": "Mr Hoagie",
    "neighborhoods": [],
    "longitude": -79.9007057,
    "state": "PA",
    "stars": 4.5,
    "latitude": 40.3543266,
    "attributes": {
        "Take-out": true,
        "Drive-Thru": false,
        "Good For": {
            "dessert": false,
            "latenight": false,
            "lunch": false,
            "dinner": false,
            "brunch": false,
            "breakfast": false
        },
        "Caters": false,
        "Noise Level": "average",
        "Takes Reservations": false,
        "Delivery": false,
        "Ambience": {
            "romantic": false,
            "intimate": false,
            "classy": false,
            "hipster": false,
            "divey": false,
            "touristy": false,
            "trendy": false,
            "upscale": false,
            "casual": false
        },
        "Parking": {
            "garage": false,
            "street": false,
            "validated": false,
            "lot": false,
            "valet": false
        },
        "Has TV": false,
        "Outdoor Seating": false,
        "Attire": "casual",
        "Alcohol": "none",
        "Waiter Service": false,
        "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
        "Good for Kids": true,
        "Good For Groups": true,
        "Price Range": 1
    },
    "type": "business"
}
```

and I want to extract all the attributes that have a value of true and store them into a table in HTML. I'm a bit stuck on this problem, but this is what I have so far

```
function saf(){
  loadJSON(function(response){
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);

    var takeout = actual_JSON.attributes;
    for(i in takeout){
      if(takeout[i]==true){
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var table = document.getElementById("service_table");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(takeout[i]);
        td.appendChild(textnode);
        tr.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }

  });
}
```

What else is necessary for me to complete this task? Is there a way for me to even for each loop through the JSON object? I'm not sure where to head from here so I'm looking for some help on this one. Should I be appending the data to the table object?

Comment: **Aside note:** There is not anything called JSON Object.  js Object or JSON string.

Comment: Instead of `i.value === true`, use `takeout[i] === true`. See this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Comment: i've updated my code. im getting the error "table is null". what would be the reason for this?

Comment: okay i got it working thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

JSON is javascript object notation which is as already name suggested javascript object. There are two ways to access JSON; by dot notation is generally like class object or by bracket notation is like array. so let's say you wanna access opeing hour on friday. you can write

```
const myjson = JSON.parse(response).
for (const key in myjson) {
    if (myjson.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + myjson[key]);
    }
}
```

so in your function.

```
function saf(){
  loadJSON(function(response){
    const actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);    

    for(i in takeout){
      if(takeout[i]===true){
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");
        const td = document.createElement("td");
        const table = document.getElementById("service_table");
        const textnode = document.createTextNode(takeout[i]);
        tr.appendChild(textnode);
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }    
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object(keys)` to get the list of properties

Use `typeof yourObject === 'object'` to check if the property is an object itself

Do a recursion to extract the properties from nested objects

```js
const obj = {
    "business_id": "5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw",
    "full_address": "4734 Lebanon Church Rd\nDravosburg, PA 15034",
    "hours": {
        "Friday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Thursday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Wednesday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        },
        "Monday": {
            "close": "21:00",
            "open": "11:00"
        }
    },
    "open": true,
    "categories": ["Fast Food",
    "Restaurants"],
    "city": "Dravosburg",
    "review_count": 4,
    "name": "Mr Hoagie",
    "neighborhoods": [],
    "longitude": -79.9007057,
    "state": "PA",
    "stars": 4.5,
    "latitude": 40.3543266,
    "attributes": {
        "Take-out": true,
        "Drive-Thru": false,
        "Good For": {
            "dessert": false,
            "latenight": false,
            "lunch": false,
            "dinner": false,
            "brunch": false,
            "breakfast": false
        },
        "Caters": false,
        "Noise Level": "average",
        "Takes Reservations": false,
        "Delivery": false,
        "Ambience": {
            "romantic": false,
            "intimate": false,
            "classy": false,
            "hipster": false,
            "divey": true,
            "touristy": false,
            "trendy": false,
            "upscale": false,
            "casual": false
        },
        "Parking": {
            "garage": false,
            "street": false,
            "validated": true,
            "lot": true,
            "valet": false
        },
        "Has TV": false,
        "Outdoor Seating": false,
        "Attire": "casual",
        "Alcohol": "none",
        "Waiter Service": false,
        "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
        "Good for Kids": true,
        "Good For Groups": true,
        "Price Range": 1
    },
    "type": "business"
};

const result = [];

const extract = (input) => Object.keys(input).forEach(key => {
  // If property is an object => recursion
  if (typeof input[key] === 'object') {
    extract(input[key]);
  }
  
  // If property is true, add it to the results
  if (input[key] === true) {
    result.push(key);
  }
});

// Execute
extract(obj.attributes);

console.log(result);
```